# IndexOutOfBound exception while inserting textview to Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating calenderview. and want to add multiple days events like google calender app so in this I am adding event at each day.I want to add one textview to linearlayout at position 2.at position 0 and 1 there is no any views are added, this is my code to insert view.

`

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.event_view);
int height 
=context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.event_image_size);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height); 
int previousViewPosition = AppConstants.eventList.get(i-1).getEvent_count();                                        
AppConstants.eventList.get(i).setEvent_count(previousViewPosition);
tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
tv.setText(AppConstants.eventList.get(i).getStrName());
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 1);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
tv.setTextSize(8);
tv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
ll_event_image.addView(tv, previousViewPosition);
```

`

it gives me error IndexOutOfBound.

> 05-02 11:57:17.162 8922-8922/com.calender.demo.calendar_api
>   W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=2 count=1
>       05-02 11:57:17.187 8922-8922/com.calender.demo.calendar_api W/System.err:     at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:4542)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4463) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4218) 05-02 11:57:17.188
>   8922-8922/com.calender.demo.calendar_api W/System.err:      at
>   com.desai.vatsal.mydynamiccalendar.DateListAdapter$DateViewHolder.setDates(DateListAdapter.java:278)
>   at
>   com.desai.vatsal.mydynamiccalendar.DateListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DateListAdapter.java:575)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)

Comment: You can't add a view to an index 2 which is not there as your LinearLayout doesn't have any view at index 0 & index 1.

Comment: So it is pretty obvious that you will get IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Apart from this your LinearLayout works in linear fashion. To add a View to index 1, you got to have a view at index 0.

Comment: I know that but i want solution to add views like this......and I got my answer...thank you.

Comment: That's great.!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the addView line

```
if(previousViewPosition >= ll_event_image.getChildCount())
   ll_event_image.addView(tv);
else
   ll_event_image.addView(tv, previousViewPosition);
```

Comment: actually i am displaying multiple day event to calender app...So this code doesn't work.It doesn't display line in all days at same position

Answer (score 1):

An `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is usually caused when you are trying to access a position that doesn't exists in your `array`for instance.

In your case, you are trying to access am object at position `index = 2` but your array has only 2 elements `position = 0 and position = 1`

**EDIT:**
The problem is mostly cause by this line

`AppConstants.eventList.get(i-1).getEvent_count();` <- Make sure you are not getting out of `eventList` bounds.

**EDIT 2:**

After reading more carefully, you are also trying to add a view in your `LinearLayout` at `previousPosition` which, in this case might not be a valid position.

Comment: but i m trying to add view to linearlayout ....there is no limit to add view to layout ..why i m getting this error?

Comment: problem is caused at this point.....ll_event_image.addView(tv, previousViewPosition);

Comment: Yes, my bad, when you are adding views in a `LinearLayout` you don't really have to specify the position, unless you already have some views and you want to add the new view before existing ones

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are trying to add a view at index 2 in LinearLayout but the LinearLayout does not have any view at indexes 0 and 1. You need to first add a view at index 0 and 1, only then you can access index 2. You can try adding an empty view if you want to leave that space blank but that's up to you and what you are trying to accomplish.